# Show the algebra of all bouned operators is a $W^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras

Given that the algebra of all bounded operators $B(H)$ on Hilbert space is a $C^*$-algebra such that $\| A^*A \| = \|A\|^2$. Then how can we show that it is also a $W^*$-algebra, where a $W^*$-algebra $X$ is a $C^*$-algebra such that $X$ is a dual space as a Banach space.

Answer (score 3):

The usual definition of a $W^*$-algebra is a weak operator closed $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$, that it's equivalent to the one you gave is a theorem of [Sakai](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540636331). More directly, the [predual to $B(H)$ is the space of trace class operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#As_the_predual_of_bounded_operators).